# How to fill Android Spinner with object name from list

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

what I am trying to is is fill the spinner options with the name of the objects in a list. I do not quite get how to implement it right

```
Storage storage = new Storage();

storageList = storage.getStorage();

Spinner spinnerStorage = findViewById(R.id.spinnerStorage);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterStorage = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, storageList);
adapterStorage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerStorage.setAdapter(adapterStorage);
```

Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. What does the `Storage` class look like? What results do you see, and how does it differ from what you expect? The XML in `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` is potentially interesting as well.

Comment: Your code seems fine, kindly post you complete code (also check if storageList actually contains something)

Comment: Thansk for the reply. Storage class is a database model class. Anyway I solved it by passing the list into an array and then passing it to the spinner, but I believe there is another way to do it, any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> salutationList = new ArrayList<>();

salutationList.add("Title");
            if (storage.getStorage() != null) {
                for (storage.getStorage() data : storage.getStorage()) {
                    salutationList.add(data.getName());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing the list into an array and then passing it to the spinner.

```
    String[] arrayStorage = new String[storageList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < storageList.size(); i++) {
        arrayStorage[i] = storageList.get(i).nameStorage;
    }

    Spinner spinnerStorage = findViewById(R.id.spinnerStorage);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterStorage = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  arrayStorage);
    adapterStorage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerStorage.setAdapter(adapterStorage);
```